# Create a Nodejs Model without database connection

Tags: node.js, data-structures, mean-stack

I want to do send data to backend , do some calculation, and send the result back to frontend. But I don't want the result to be save into database.

this is a one of the model schema that I have

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate')


var RefCompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
currency: {
    mxn: Number,
    php: Number
},
date: Date
})

RefCompanySchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)
const RefCompany = mongoose.model('RefCompany', RefCompanySchema)

module.exports = RefCompany;
```

but the new one that I'm want to make has to be like this

```
  var statistic = {
        youPay: Number,
        theyGet: Number,
        fee: Number,
        feeIncluded: Boolean,
        trueCost: Number,
        trueCostPercentage: Number
    }
```

So how Can I create a statistic model, that is not connected to database?

Comment: What you describe seems to have nothing at all to do with a database.  Just POST some data from client to server using either a form post or an ajax post, create a route on your server to handle the POST request, process the data that was sent and return a response back to the client.  No database needed anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, @jfriend00. I know there is no database needed, but what I'm asking is do I need to create a model?  because the 'var statistic'  is the response that going back to the client. if yes how can create a model?  what would be the format/straucture of it?

Comment: If you're not going to be communicating with a database, then no you don't need a model.  Just use a plain Javascript object definition and send back a JSON representation of that object like with `res.json(myObject)`.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00 . I'll try it now